# Dynamically addition of select item created via json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to create table row dynamically with select values of a json array 
the row is added in the row but the other drop-down list are not working in the following code when i trying to concatenate the id of the select with that call the function i got error .I am attaching  the  link of the jsfiddle where i am not getting error only with select drop down list nod adding extra field [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avishekp4/ncv4yhoz/).How do i resolve the error for the same effect as the link.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h4> Honours Selection</h4>  
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 657px"  id="customFields" >
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 222px">
<col style="width: 216px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
<col style="width: 219px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2"><br>Honours</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="4">General</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">Bank Transaction Details</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj"rowspan="2" >Add More</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub1</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub2</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub3</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub4</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction id</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-30rh"><select name ="hons[]" id="select1"onchange="">
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
    <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2" name="session[]">
</select>
</td>
<td class="tg-30rh"> <select name="sub1[]"id="select2">
              </select>
</td>
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub2[]"id="select3">
</select></td>
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub3[]"id="select4">
</select></td>
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub4[]"id="select5">
</select></td>
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_id[]"></td>
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_date[]"></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){var x=2;
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr>\
    <td class="tg-30rh"><select name ="hons[]" id='+'select1'+x+' onchange="updateSelect(this.id);">\
    <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>\
    <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>\
    <option value="English">English</option>\
</select>\
<select id="ddl2" name="session[]">\
</select>\
</td>\
<td class="tg-30rh"> <select name="sub1[]" id='+'select2'+x+'>\
              </select>\
</td>\
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub2[]" id='+'select3'+x+'>\
</select></td>\
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub3[]" id='+'select4'+x+'>\
</select></td>\
<td class="tg-30rh"><select name="sub4[]" id='+'select4'+x+'>\
</select></td>\
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_id[]"></td>\
    <td class ="tg-30rh"><input type="text" name="tran_date[]"></td>\
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>\
  </tr>');x++;
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});

var jsonObj = {"Hindi":[["History","Sociology","Economics"],"Philosophy","Political Science","English"],"Bengali":[["History","Sociology"],"Sanskrit","Philosophy","Political Science"],"English":[["History","Sociology","Economics"],"Philosophy","Political Science",["Bengali","Hindi"]],"History ":["Philosophy"," Political Science",["Bengali"," Hindi"]," English"],"Political Science":[[" History "," Sociology"," Economics"],"Philosophy",["Bengali "," Hindi"],"English"],"Philosophy":[[" History"," Sociology"]," Sanskrit","Political Science",["Bengali","Hindi"]]}

function updateSelect(id) {
    //alert("#"+id+"1");
    var getOpts = function(raw){
        var values = raw;
        if (!(raw instanceof Array)){
            values = [raw, ""];
        }
        var result = [];
        values.forEach(function(obj){
            result.push(new Option(obj, obj));
        });
        return result;
    };


    var newKey = $("#"+id+"1").val();
    var mappings = [{"#"+id+"2":0},{"#"+id+"3":1},{"#"+id+"4":2},{"#"+id+"5":3}];//getting error in this line SyntaxError: missing : after property id var mappings = [{"#"+id+"2":0},{"#"+id+"3":1}, {"#"+id+"4":2},//{"#"+id+"5":3} ]; near +

    var selected = jsonObj[newKey];

    mappings.forEach(function(mapping){
        var selector = Object.keys(mapping)[0];
        var index = mapping[selector];
        $(selector).empty();
        var opts = getOpts(selected[index]);
        $(selector).append(opts);
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#select1").change(updateSelect);
    updateSelect(); // For initial page load.
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the initial `id` coming from when the `updateSelect` event is triggered? The first and only event is event itself. Do you mean to get the `event.target`?

Comment: initial id will be the first select box(select1)@Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: But where is it coming from? You call it with no parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a typo, please format your code and then decide if you need to ask a question.

```
var mappings = [{"#"+id+"2":0},{"#"+id+"3":1},{"#"+id+"4":2},{"#"+id+5":3}];//getting error in this line
```

#### Formatted Code

```
var mappings = [
    {"#"+id+"2":0},
    {"#"+id+"3":1},
    {"#"+id+"4":2},
    {"#"+id+5":3}   // <- Do you see the error now?
];
```

#### Fixed

```
var mappings = [
    {"#"+id+"2":0},
    {"#"+id+"3":1},
    {"#"+id+"4":2},
    {"#"+id+"5":3}   // <- Fixed, you need to add the opening quote before the '5'.
];
```

I forked your JSFiddle and cleaned it up a bit: [jsfiddle.net/b55bykec](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/b55bykec/)

### Update

You need to build the mapping, since you cannot generate dynamic keys inline with your object definition:

```
var mappings = [2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(map, val, index) {
    var key = '#' + id + val;
    map[key] = index;
    return map;
}, {});

var selected = jsonObj[newKey];

$.each(mappings, function (selector, index) {
    $(selector).empty().append(getOpts(selected[index]));
});
```

There were some changes that needed to be changed to make your code work. All of the following changes below were made to make the *Working Example*, at the bottom, work.

- I moved all inline styles to a stylesheet. You had many of the same values, so consolidating helps you manage better in the future.
- I changed `customFields` to `custom-fields`. CSS class names and IDs should not be camelcase. Words are usually separated by hyphens. This may sound pedantic, but it helps you from confusing them with JavaScript variables.
- I moved `x` out into the global scope. `x` is a static value that should auto-increment each time a new row is added.
- You had two "select4" IDs added to each dynamic row. I changed the second to "select5".
- Your generated IDs were not unique enough, I added a dash to separate col-row.

  ```
  '<select name ="hons[]" id="' + 'select1-' + x + '">'
  ```
- In order for all new select boxes to listen to the change event, you need to add the listener to the parent container and listen to changes on the children.

  ```
  $('#custom-fields').on('change', 'select[id^="select1-"]', updateSelect);
  ```

---

### Working Example

```js
var x = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#custom-fields").append([
      '<tr>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name ="hons[]" id="' + 'select1-' + x + '">',
      '<option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>',
      '<option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>',
      '<option value="English">English</option>',
      '</select> ',
      '<select id="ddl2" name="session[]"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub1[]" id="select2-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub2[]" id="select3-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub3[]" id="select4-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub4[]" id="select5-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<input type="text" name="tran_id[]" />',
      '</td>',
      '<td class ="tg-30rh">',
      '<input type="text" name="tran_date[]" />',
      '</td>',
      '<td>',
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>',
      '</td>',
      '</tr>'
    ].join(''));

    $('#select1-' + x).trigger('change');

    x++;
  });
  $("#custom-fields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});

var jsonObj = {
  "Hindi": [
    ["History", "Sociology", "Economics"], "Philosophy", "Political Science", "English"
  ],
  "Bengali": [
    ["History", "Sociology"], "Sanskrit", "Philosophy", "Political Science"
  ],
  "English": [
    ["History", "Sociology", "Economics"], "Philosophy", "Political Science", ["Bengali", "Hindi"]
  ],
  "History ": ["Philosophy", " Political Science", ["Bengali", " Hindi"], " English"],
  "Political Science": [
    [" History ", " Sociology", " Economics"], "Philosophy", ["Bengali ", " Hindi"], "English"
  ],
  "Philosophy": [
    [" History", " Sociology"], " Sanskrit", "Political Science", ["Bengali", "Hindi"]
  ]
};

function updateSelect(e) {
  var targetId = e.target.id;
  var id = parseInt(targetId.match(/[\w\d]+\-(\d+)$/)[1], 10);

  var getOpts = function(raw) {
    raw = Array.isArray(raw) ? raw : [raw, ''];

    return raw.map(function(obj) {
      return new Option(obj, obj);
    });
  };

  var newKey = $('#select1-' + id).val();

  var mappings = [2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(map, val, index) {
    var key = '#select' + val + '-' + id;
    map[key] = index;
    return map;
  }, {});

  var selected = jsonObj[newKey];

  $.each(mappings, function (selector, index) {
    $(selector).empty().append(getOpts(selected[index]));
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#custom-fields').on('change', 'select[id^="select1-"]', updateSelect);     
  $('#select1-0').trigger('change'); // For initial page load.
});
```

```css
.col-wide {
  width: 222px;
}

.col-narrow {
  width: 216px;
}

.col-normal {
  width: 219px;
}

#custom-fields {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 657px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4> Honours Selection</h4> 
<table class="tg" id="custom-fields">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-wide" />
    <col class="col-narrow" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">
      <br />Honours
    </th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="4">General</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">Bank Transaction Details</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">Add More</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub1</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub2</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub3</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub4</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction id</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="hons[]" id="select1-0" onchange="">
        <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
        <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
      </select>
      <select id="ddl2" name="session[]">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub1[]" id="select2-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub2[]" id="select3-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub3[]" id="select4-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub4[]" id="select5-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="tran_id[]" />
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="tran_date[]" />
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not working out  getting error @Mr. Polywhirl . [see](http://jsbin.com/jelagiyabu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @avi: My updated code above, populates the other select boxes properly.

Comment: if i add new row(click on Add) of select, the drop-downs are not working except for first row. they are not populating .@Mr. Polywhirl

Comment: @Avi: I had to make some changes to your code. I believe it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an expression as a property name.

UPDATE:

Try something like this:

```
var mappings = [];
["#"+id+"2","#"+id+"3","#"+id+"4","#"+id+"5"].forEach(function(e,i) {
    var o = {};
    o[e] = i;
    mappings.push(o);
});
```

Comment: so how do i populate the dynamically so that all drop-down box will work@Maurice Perry

Comment: @ Maruice Perry the error is gone but still not getting the effect    please [see this](http://jsbin.com/rodiqebipe/1/edit?html,js,output) i think i am missing some thing.

Comment: @avi my mistake: An "s" is missing (mappings)

Comment: @avi also, you're not passing any id to updateSelect